# JavaScript style.height shaking unintentionally

Tags: javascript, css, transition

http://stadskoll.nu/restaurang.php

If you press the string of text called **Visa/dölj mer information** which is in a grey font, you will see that the effect occurring is shaking. This is not intentional and I cant figure out what's wrong.

To clarify, I want to know what's causing this "shaky" effect and be able to remove it.

**HTML :**

```
<!--VAL1-->
<div id="val1">
    <div id="information">
        <namn>
            <a href=""></a>
        </namn>
        <br>
        <a id="funktion" onclick="toggle('val1');toggleoff_val1('val1');">visa/dölj mer information</a>
        <br>
        <div id="star2" style="background-position:0 -0px">
            <div id="stars1">
                <div class="first"  onmouseover="starmove('-32px','stars1')" onmouseout="starnormal('stars1')" onclick="rate('','1');succes()"></div>
                <div class="first" onmouseover="starmove('-64px','stars1')" onmouseout="starnormal('stars1')" onclick="rate('','2');succes()"></div>
                <div class="first" onmouseover="starmove('-96px','stars1')" onmouseout="starnormal('stars1')" onclick="rate('','3');succes()"></div>
                <div class="first" onmouseover="starmove('-128px','stars1')" onmouseout="starnormal('stars1')" onclick="rate('','4');succes()"></div>
                <div class="first" onmouseover="starmove('-160px','stars1')" onmouseout="starnormal('stars1')" onclick="rate('','5');succes()"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="txt"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <information></information>
    </div>
    <div id="bilder">
        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup('bildval1');fade('fadebild1')"><img src="" /></a>
        <br/>
        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup('kartaval1');fade('fadekarta1')"><img src="http://stadskoll.nu/bilder/karta.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#val1 {
    width:83%;
    height:75px;
    border-top:1px;
    border-top-style:groove;
    margin-left:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;    
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Firefox 4 */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Opera */                
}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
<script>   
    function toggle(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.height == '175px')
          e.style.height = '75px';
              else
          e.style.height = '175px';         
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it might help. You cannot make up html elements. `<namn>` and `<information>` are not valid html elements. If you validate your site you will see that there are a lot of errors in your html. And you are mixing different styles of html. For example as you are not using the html5 doctype you must close your `br` tags like this `<br />`. [Validation Results](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstadskoll.nu%2Frestaurang.php). If you correct all these issues it will lead to a much more stable site that will work better across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the `display:inline` on the maincontentbox.
If you add `vertical-align:top` it will disappear.

What I believe is happening is that, since by default it is aligned to the baseline, the browser is making the div taller.  Since the div is taller it has to resize the parent container and then move the div to the bottom of the line.

Comment: Yeah, that fixes it. I realize now maybe i should have added the parent container's code in the post. Thanks for taking the extra time and check into it! :)